# How to run stored procedure (authentication) and then display query results

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to display my query results in Excel for some visuals etc using PowerBI.

To get the data you first need to authenticate yourself using a stored procedure which issues a session_id and then it will display the query results.

When I run this in PowerBI it gives me the sessionID but the query results are not displayed

I'm trying the below -

```
    let
    Auth = Sql.Database("localhost", "business_data", [Query="EXEC session_authenticate_sp 'admin_service';"])
    Source = Sql.Database("localhost", "business_data", [Query=" SELECT #(lf)  o.[style_]#(lf), o.[owner_id] AS bus_owner_id#(lf), o.[en_id]#(lf), o.[form_id]#(lf), o.[formexceptions_id]#(lf), o.[ee_id]#(lf), o.[image_id]#(lf)FROM report_forms_owners o#(lf)INNER JOIN financial_owners fo#(lf)ON o.owner_id=fo.id"])
in
    Source
```

but this returns nothing but in SSMS there is data. I think its because its to do with the Auth running together with Source. Because Auth returns a result if ran seperatley. Source returns nothing (expected since no authentication took place)

Can anyone assist?

Many thanks

Comment: can anyone assist?